# Beamer top navigation bar with long section titles

Tags: beamer, navigation

So I have this beamer presentation with 5 sections. Each section as a long title so the navigation bar on top is cutoff.

I do not want to change its aspect. But is there anyway I can keep the section titles unchanged but on the top navigation bar it would show up something else.

E.g. keep the section titles as:

1. Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Section Title 1
2. Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Section Title 2
3. etc

But on top navigation bar show something like:

1. LST 1
2. LST 2
3. LST 3

etc.

Below two pictures. One with the current output, and one with the desired output.

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Edited: MWE below with the full preamble:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%
    \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{bbm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{ mathrsfs }
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{textpos}

    \definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{140,140,172}
    \definecolor{bluegreen}{RGB}{173,173,224}
    \definecolor{lightbluegreen}{RGB}{204,0,51}
    \definecolor{cyan}{RGB}{30,24,83}
    \usetheme{default}
    \useinnertheme {rectangles}
    \setbeamercolor{enumerate items}{fg=lightbluegreen}
    \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
    \setbeamertemplate{items}[circle] %bola em todos bullets
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[default]
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \color{darkblue}\insertsectionhead\ \ \ \ |
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
    \insertsectionhead\color{darkblue}\ \ \ \ |
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{myheadline}
    \Tiny\hspace*{4mm} {\hspace*{2ex}\color{white}|\hspace*{-2ex}}\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0ex}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }

    \setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}
    \hspace{0cm}\color{bluegreen}\insertframenumber{}/\color{bluegreen}\inserttotalframenumber}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg = white, bg =darkblue}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg = white}
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size = \large}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=darkblue}
    \captionsetup{compatibility=false}
    \def\code#1{\texttt{#1}}
    \newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=10pt,text margin right=10pt}
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
    \newenvironment{wideitemize}{\itemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{10pt}}{\enditemize}
    \usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{hl/.style={
        set fill color=black!00,
        set border color=red!80!black,
      },
    }

    \AtBeginSection[]
    {
     \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{Outline}
     \tableofcontents[currentsection]
     \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
     \end{frame}
    }

    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}



    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
      \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}


    \section{LST 1}{Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Section Title 1}

    \begin{frame}
      Placeholder
    \end{frame}

    \section{LST 2}{Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Section Title 2}

    \begin{frame}
      Placeholder
    \end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
  Placeholder
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional argument of the section command as follows:

`\section[LST 1] {Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Section Title 1}`.

Comment: Actually, that also changes the titles on the outline slide.  Which I do not want to change.

Comment: @phdstudent: Could you please edit your question and add  minimal wokring example that others can use for testing? As far as I recall, the long version should be used in the table of contents. However, this might vary depending on the theme used.

Comment: Edited with MWE. Thanks,

Comment: samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz on a different stackexchange question, just noted that the problem is with the syntax. Quoting from him: About your beamer problem: the syntax in your example is wrong, you want \section[LST 1]{Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Section Title 1} --- notice the square brackets – samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz